# how can i select only the links when i bring up the entire class to R?

Tags: html, r, web, rvest

library:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
```

when i use this code i bring up the entire class of the html for site:

```
 links_avai <- paste0("https://avai.com.br/page", seq(from = 1, to = 2)) %>%
  map(. %>%
        read_html() %>%
        html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@class="gdlr-blog-title"]')
```

runnig it i have te follow result:

```
    [[1]]
{xml_nodeset (8)}
[1] <h3 class="gdlr-blog-title"><a href="https://www.avai.com.br/novo/entenda-como-funciona-o-processo-de-apresentacao-d ...
[2] <h3 class="gdlr-blog-title"><a href="https://www.avai.com.br/novo/ingressos-a-venda-para-avai-x-barra-3a-rodada-do-c ...
[3] <h3 class="gdlr-blog-title"><a href="https://www.avai.com.br/novo/dona-nesi-furlani-recebe-homenagem-do-avai/">Dona  ...
[4] <h3 class="gdlr-blog-title"><a href="https://www.avai.com.br/novo/avai-e-superado-pela-chapecoense-na-ressacada/">Av ...
[5] <h3 class="gdlr-blog-title"><a href="https://www.avai.com.br/novo/edital-de-convocacao-reuniao-extraordinaria-do-con ...
[6] <h3 class="gdlr-blog-title"><a href="https://www.avai.com.br/novo/catarinense-2022-confira-o-guia-da-partida-avai-x- ...
[7] <h3 class="gdlr-blog-title"><a href="https://www.avai.com.br/novo/avai-finaliza-preparacao-para-enfrentar-a-chapecoe ...
[8] <h3 class="gdlr-blog-title"><a href="https://www.avai.com.br/novo/catarinense-2022-arbitragem-para-avai-x-chapecoens ..
```

whit that in mind how can improve my code to selecet only the link from the class?

i alredy tried that code below, but it did not work

```
links_avai <- paste0("https://avai.com.br/page", seq(from = 1, to = 2)) %>%
  map(. %>%
        read_html() %>%
        html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@class="gdlr-blog-title"]') %>% 
        html_element("href")
```

the result was:

```
 {xml_nodeset (8)}
[1] <NA>
[2] <NA>
[3] <NA>
[4] <NA>
[5] <NA>
[6] <NA>
[7] <NA>
[8] <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the links use `html_attrs`, the links are attached to node/element `a`.

```
url<-"https://www.avai.com.br/novo/"

url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('.gdlr-blog-title') %>% html_nodes('a') %>% 
  html_attr('href')

[1] "https://www.avai.com.br/novo/se-e-baya-e-bom-atacante-paulo-baya-e-apresentado-no-leao/"              
[2] "https://www.avai.com.br/novo/comunicado-arquivada-denuncia-no-stjd/"                                  
[3] "https://www.avai.com.br/novo/sob-chuva-leao-se-reapresenta-nesta-tarde-de-quinta-feira/"              
[4] "https://www.avai.com.br/novo/entenda-como-funciona-o-processo-de-apresentacao-de-atletas/"            
[5] "https://www.avai.com.br/novo/ingressos-a-venda-para-avai-x-barra-3a-rodada-do-catarinense-fort-2022/" 
[6] "https://www.avai.com.br/novo/dona-nesi-furlani-recebe-homenagem-do-avai/"                             
[7] "https://www.avai.com.br/novo/avai-e-superado-pela-chapecoense-na-ressacada/"                          
[8] "https://www.avai.com.br/novo/edital-de-convocacao-reuniao-extraordinaria-do-conselho-deliberativo-11/"
```